# What is NSMutable Array/String/URL?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

Sometimes I get errors when defining a variable as `NSArray/String/URL`, it can often be solved by changing it to `NSMutableArray/String/URL`.

What is the difference between them? People say you can't change the value of a `NSString`, but why not since I defined it as a variable with a `var`?

Please use Swift 2 code to explain.

Here's code example:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

    static let baseURLString = "https://api.500px.com/v1"
    static let consumerKey = "My_Key"

    case PopularPhotos(Int)
    case PhotoInfo(Int, ImageSize)
    case Comments(Int, Int)

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
    //Error: Type does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible' with Alamofire. 
    //I solved this problem by changing it to NSMutableRequest. 

        let (path, parameters) : (String, [String: AnyObject]) = {

            switch self {

            //3 cases. 

            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NS types are coming from Cocoa (some would say Objective-c, but actually they don't exist in Objective-C so they were created in the NextStep libraries and then used by Apple in Cocoa after they bought NextStep -> hence the NS prefix)

NSArray/String/URL are similar to let myVar = "aString"

and

NSMutableArray/String/URL are similar to var myVar = "aString"

the first one cannot be changed after it's set the second one can be. Why are you using the Cocoa/Objective-C types and not native Swift types ?

**EDIT (see comments)**

in Swift you can define a string:

```
var anEmtpyString = String()
```

or

```
var anEmtpyString = ""
```

in the second case Swift is intelligent enough to deduct that the type is a String. If you use 'var' the string is Mutable, meaning you can change it afterwards. So I can do :

```
var myString = "first text"
myString = "another text"
```

if you're using 'let' you create a references to the string, also called Immutable

```
let myString = "first text"
myString = "another text" // <- the compiler won't accept this !
```

In those examples I have used the native String type from Swift, which exists in both Swift 1.2 and 2

I could also use the Cocoa/Objective types NSString, NSMutableString but most of the time there is no need for it. It can be handy if you're using frameworks which are written in Objective-C. It's easier then to you since you don't have to cast from String to NSString/NSMutableString. (which is of course possible)

In Objective-C there is no let or var keyword so there you used NSString (for let) and NSMutableString (for var).

The same goes for NSArray/NSMutableArray

More info : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

PS the answer from gnasher729 is a bit more technical and tell you how it goes around behind the scenes. It al has to do with pointers, which were very present in Objective-C but are much more hidden in Swift. If you come from a background where you have learned pointers it will make thing clearer, if not I'm not sure if it'll help you. If you want me to expand on this please tell.

Comment: Oh I was doing it according to Raywenderlich's tutorials, which is written in  Swift 1.2.

Comment: So that's to say when I `var` something into a NSString, the `var` works the same as `let` ? O_O

Comment: It's not wrong to use those types. But swift has native String, Array types, so I use them. I'm going to edit my answer in a few moments (I have more formatting options there)

Comment: `NS`types does not come from Objective-C. They come from Cocoa.

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad technically you're 100% right, but for beginners it's already quite confusing: Objective-C, Cocoa, swift,... so that's why I used that generic term. Anyway I adapted my answer a bit to be more correct ;)

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to add this. Indeed, it is without any meaning for your excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A.

In Objective-C many types of your daily routine are not built-in types. That means that they are not part of the programming language.

Therefore the framework Foundation defines that types as classes as any other class. There is no difference to classes like `NSImage`, `NSManagedObject`, `NSWhatever`. You do not have a language level documentation. They are documented as part of the Framework. You can treat them as every other class including subclassing, categories on it and so on. There is simply nothing special with them. (You could completely replace them, but there is little reason to do so.)

B.

In Objective-C every instance object is allocated on heap ("dynamically"). Since instances of `NSString` are usual instance objects, you do the same with them. The return value of such a construction is not an instance object, but a reference to an instance object. That means that all instance objects including instances of `NSString` are treated "by reference".

When you define a variable with the "type of string" you do not define a string instance, but a reference to the string:

```
NSString *referenceToString;
```

This referene is always a variable. In Swift it would look like this:

```
var string : String;
```

The analogon to a const in Objective-C is defined with the key word `const`.

```
NSString * const referenceToString;
```

But there is a big difference: Since the variable you declare is a reference, the constness can be related to the reference or to the object. In the first case you couldn't change the reference, in the latter case you could not change the object. The above syntax means: Constant reference to an `NSString` instance. Therefore you are not allowed to assign a value to that reference. (I. e. referencing another string object.)

These constant references are not very popular in Objective-C, because in most cases the constness of the reference is meaningless.

The constness of the string *object* itself is modeled by the type of the string object. `NSString` means constant string *object*, `NSMutableString` means variable string *object*.

Therefore, if you want to have a sting that can be mutated, use `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`.

```
NSMutableString *referenceToAMutableString;
NSString *referenceToAnImmutableString;
```

Comment: Again perfectly correct, and with my background (coming from the days we used pointers and handles in MacPascal) perfectly clear, but I guess quite complex for newbies with almost zero programming experience who are never confronted with referencing variables trough pointers. Still one vote up for going to the metal ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are value objects and reference objects. For example, Int and String are value objects, NSNumber and NSString are reference object. Swift struct instance are value objects, Swift class instances are reference objects.

For a reference object, the variable is *not* the object. It is a reference to the object. So a "let" variable cannot be changed, which means it refers to one object and cannot be made to refer to another object. A "var" variable can be changed, which means it can be made to refer to a different object. But both say nothing about the object itself. An NSArray object cannot be modified, an NSMutableArray can be modified. Whether you use a let or var variable to refer to the object only means the variable cannot or can be made to refer to a different variable, it doesn't say whether you can modify the object itself.